# Error "mount: operation not permitted" when trying to mount system as read/write

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, mount, system-error, sony-xperia

I am trying to mount system as `r\w` and every app couldn't do it including root explorer and link2sd. I am using Xperia z2 android v4.4.4 and I the device is rooted and I have restarted the phone.

I get the following eeors when trying to do this:

`mount -o mount,rw rootfs /
 mount: operation not permitted`

Comment: `rootfs` is not your system partition. Is that what you actually intended to remount? What's the end goal that you're trying to achieve? More context might be helpful.

Comment: @eldarerathis yes I intended to mount the root of my device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount /system rewritable or read-only? (RW/RO)](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/how-to-mount-system-rewritable-or-read-only-rw-ro)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you remount root as read-write:

```
 mount -o remount,rw /
```

If you want to remount the system partition as read-write:

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```