# How to mount /system rewritable or read-only? (RW/RO)

Tags: adb, root-access, mount, system

How can I mount the `/system` directory rewritable or read-only on my Android phone?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There are a few methods how you can mount your `/system` directory RW or RO. However, it will require root.

## Method 1:

1. Connect your phone to the computer. (Make sure USB debugging is enabled on your phone)
2. Open `CMD`/`Terminal` on your PC.

   - Windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then type `cmd`.
   - Ubuntu: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
   - Mac: Navigate to `/Applications/Utilities/` and double-click on **Terminal**.
3. Type this:

   1. `adb shell`
   2. `su`
   3. Choose one: (for security mount `/system` back to RO when finished)

      - Mount system RW: `mount -o rw,remount /system`
      - Mount system RO: `mount -o ro,remount /system`

## Method 2:

1. Open `terminal` on your android phone (download [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)):
2. Type this in the `terminal`:

   1. `su`
   2. Choose one: (for security mount `/system` back to RO when finished)

      - Mount system RW: `mount -o rw,remount /system`
      - Mount system RO: `mount -o ro,remount /system`

## Android 2.3

For people running Android 2.3 and the command fails, look at this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/125437/95577

Comment: It seems this (method 1) does not work on newer Android any more. I am trying to do it on Android emulator running Android 6, but always get an error "mount: Read-only file system". I've run adb root, but it makes no difference. Any idea on what could be done?

Comment: I got it, kind of. I have to use -writable-system command line option when starting the emulator. Then the first adb remount seems to succeed. Seems ... I have not seen it change to rw yet.

Comment: emulator -writable is still the correct answer.

Comment: "For people running Android 2.3" -- that phrasing doesn't communicate very well.  I am guessing you mean >=2.3 or <=2.3 (or, less likely, *exactly* 2.3 if there's a particular bug in 2.3 only) but we don't know which or why.

Comment: For me, `mount -o rw,remount /system` gives `mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts`. However, `mount -o rw,remount /` works.

Answer (score 5):

**`-writable-system` for the emulator**

When launching the emulator after a build with, you must use:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_x86_64-eng
emulator -show-kernel -verbose -writable-system
```

Then, for future runs, you must keep the `-writable-system` option, or else image changes will not be visible:

```
emulator -show-kernel -verbose -writable-system
```

[`-verbose`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445464/how-to-show-which-options-are-passed-to-qemu-when-launching-the-android-emulator) shows us that the emulator switches from the default `-drive`:

```
if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/path/to/aosp/8.1.0_r60/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system-qemu.img,read-only
```

to:

```
if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/path/to/aosp/8.1.0_r60/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576
```

Therefore it:

- removes `,read-only`
- uses `system-qemu.img.qcow2` instead of `system-qemu.img`.

  This implies that changes will only be visible afterwards if you pass `-writable-sytem` on future boots after the change was made!

  We can see that the qcow2 image is just a small [overlay](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/CreateSnapshot) on top of the base image since:

  ```
  qemu-img info /path/to/aosp/8.1.0_r60/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system-qemu.img.qcow2
  ```

  contains:

  ```
  backing file: /path/to/aosp/8.1.0_r60/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system-qemu.img
  ```

The emulator `-help` also confirms this:

```
emulator -help
```

contains:

```
-writable-system     make system & vendor image writable after 'adb remount'
```

**`adb remount` + `adb root`**

I think this is just a shortcut for `mount` as mentioned at https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110928/126934 , but it is very convenient:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell
```

`adb help` contains:

```
 root                     restart adbd with root permissions
 remount
     remount /system, /vendor, and /oem partitions read-write
```

**Restore the original system image**

Same as for userdata: remove the `.qcow2` overlay, and re-generate it manually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446680/how-to-reset-the-userdata-image-when-building-android-aosp-and-running-it-on-the

Answer (score 0):

I really struggled with that until I used MT Manager (I tried a lot of root explorers and only MT Manager works for me). It isn't on Play Store, so you have to search for it online.

If it didn't work, try the Magisk module called OverlayFS. If you can't find it, here it is: [OverlayFS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachments/magisk-overlayfs-sfile-mobi-zip.5821499/) (direct download from XDA).