# CM11 - Cant remove the camera app

Tags: cyanogenmod, camera

I am running CM11(Nightly) on my Galaxy Tab P1000 and I cannot remove the camera app that came with it. I have tried the following command-:

```
adb shell rm -f /system/app/camera2.apk
```

But this has absolutely no effect. Please advise on how to remove the camera app because it is not working properly.

Comment: Is `/system` mounted as `rw` (read-write)? Also check if you need root permission to delete that file.

Comment: To mount /system RW, look here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/110927/95577

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Yup it was mounted as `rw`. Just checked it. So what do I do now ? Nothing happens when I `rm` the app apk. It still stays in `/system/`

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Can tell me how to set root permissions to delete that file ?

Comment: Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out how to do this. It seems since I didn't have root permission on the app therefore I was not able to delete it.

I did the following-:

1. First I set up ADB on Windows.
2. Connected my device
3. Typed in `adb root`
4. `adb remount`
5. `adb shell`
6. `su`
7. `chmod 777 /system/app/Camera2.apk`
8. `rm -f /system/app/Camera2.apk`

And voila I could delete the app.