# Mount /system on Android 10 with Magisk

Tags: mount, system, magisk, android-10

I am using Magisk 20.4 and trying to mount /system on a Google Pixel (1st gen) running Android 10.

I have tried using:

```
adb shell su -c mount -o rw,remount /system
```

that gives:

> mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts

The following also do not work:

```
adb shell su -c mount -o rw,remount /
```

> '/dev/root' is read-only

```
adb shell su -c mount -o rw,remount /sbin/.magisk/mirror/system_root
```

> '/sbin/.magisk/block/system_root' is read-only

I was also curious whether stuff in /sbin/.magisk/rootdir/system/ can actually override stuff in /system/ but that doesn't seem to be the case..

Has anyone managed to mount /system on Android 10? Is this issue specific to Google Pixel?

Cheers,
Paschalis

##### Trying Hack5 suggestion gives me:

> mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts

Since I knew that `/sbin/.magisk/mirror/system_root` was a valid mount point, Ive tried the following, which still fails:

```
mount -wo remount /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system$(getprop
 ro.boot.slot_suffix)  /sbin/.magisk/block/system_root
```

> mount: '/sbin/.magisk/block/system_root' not in /proc/mounts

## UPDATE:

Turns out it's [impossible](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1170404631865778177) to mount /system on a factory image of Google Pixel. But, I was missing the whole point of `Magisk`! So I made a few modules and I can override/add the system libs and bins that I need. There is even support for `apex` on Android 10!

Answer (score 1):

Your second command is correct, but the virtual block device is read only. IIRC, this is caused by the a/b mapping virtualisations.

Referring to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/158890/171244, you can see that specifying the correct block device will help. Try:

```
adb shell
su -c mount -wo remount /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system$(getprop ro.boot.slot_suffix) /system
```

This will switch from the virtual mapper (/dev/root) which is read-only, to the actual partition block device, making it writable

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it does not work (see my updated question).

Comment: sorry, i made a typo, the final /system should just be /

Comment: I had also tested that and I haven't included on my edited answer. Still no luck :/ At this point I'm wondering even if it's possible!

Comment: It's definitely possible from TWRP

Comment: TWRP isn't supported on android10, but even temporarily booting into it gives: `'/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system_a' is read-only`.

Comment: I've never had a device with A/B so I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

ext4-dedup/logical partitions are ro by design

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from Magisk.

I have a boot.img that I patched using Magisk 7.2.3. The latest 7.5.1 keeps giving me that error msg. Try using the old Magisk and you won't have that "mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts" error.

Comment: you recommend to install magisk manager 7.2.3 right ? and I can see only 7.2.0 versions only..is that right you mentioned or it is 7.3.2  Magisk Manager version ?