# Cannot disable com.motorola.ccc.ota

Tags: adb, system-apps

Since "Motorola Software Update" decided to download Nougat OTA without asking my opinion, I declared a war. But the weapons I use are broken.

Withot `su`:

```
shell@athene:/ $ pm disable com.motorola.ccc.ota
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to 
change component state from pid=22598, uid=2000, package uid=10009
```

With `su`:

```
1|shell@athene:/ $ su
root@athene:/ # pm disble com.motorola.ccc.ota
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

How can I disable this app?

I wouldn't like to `rm` the app entirely (if possible), have everything system-less so far. If relevant, I am using Moto G4 with Marshmallow.

Comment: Maybe you just [didn't remount](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110928/94888) you system partition before disabling?

Comment: @Suncatcher Good idea, but... I can only remount system in superuser session, and ```pm``` doesn't work in it. Superusers have either separate mount namespaces or share it with ```init```. I cannot see a way to make system ```rw``` for unprivileged user. Maybe I miss something? :\

Comment: You can try to remount inline with `adb shell su -c "mount -o remount,rw /system"` and then run `pm`, however I am not sure it will work.

Comment: It throws exactly the same exception :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop OTA updates (and notifications) on Moto devices, you don't use Package Manager, you will need to "freeze" the service...

Google Play Store has many apps that will allow you to 'freeze' the OTA Update service. [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) is a common example.

Alternatively, with a 'root access' file explorer, you can delete or rename the following files:

/system/etc/security/otacerts.zip
/system/priv-app/3c_ota/3c_ota.apk

These additional files can be removed or renamed: (If you still get an OTA Update notification)

/system/priv-app/3c_checkin/3c_checkin.apk
/system/priv-app/3c_devicemanagement/3c_devicemanagement.apk
/system/priv-app/3c_notification/3c_notification.apk

[Reference](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=71770306&postcount=2001)

Comment: AFAIK Titanium Backup uses exactly ```pm disable``` to "freeze" an app, so it  shouldn't work either. Ended up making a backup and just renaming the OTA app :( I guess I just won't find a nicer solution. Neat idea with removing the certificates btw.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at

> With su:
>
> ```
> 1|shell@athene:/ $ su
> root@athene:/ # pm disble com.motorola.ccc.ota
> Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
> ```

I've noticed that there is a spelling error in the "disable"  The original statement says "disble".  This message is just FYI.