# Android x86: remounting /system : /dev/loop1 is read only

Tags: system, android-x86

I try to remove google apps from android x86 dowloaded from [here](http://www.android-x86.org/download) and I managed to make it run over virtualbox, afterwards in **installed** it to a virtual hard disk.

But I want on it to remove any google-based apps and run with free-software alternatives. So I installed via fdroid the `/system/app mover` but when I try to move any app I get the error:

> Could not remount /system

So using the onboard terminal I followed the [instructions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/how-to-mount-system-rewritable-or-read-only-rw-ro#110928) provided.

I managed to become root and run the command:

```
mount -o rw,remount system
```

But I got the error:

```
'/dev/loop1' is read-only
```

How I can fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you installed the androidx86 using fast install from advanced options. Please reinstall the Android x84 and select the /system to get mounted as rw as you can see in the image bellow:

[image: Mount /system as writable]

PS: Even if the image is rather old it still stays the same during installation.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this, you just reinstall it on the same drive. Say do not format say skip to the GRUB question and then yes to making /system writable.

It will then reboot and everything will be as it was with a writable /system folder. I know the last guy said this but he/she didn't mention you won't lose your files :D

Posting here as I couldn't find this anywhere else.