# Uninstall TWRP application without PlayStore?

Tags: twrp, uninstallation

I accidentally agreed to the annoying TWRP application (me.twrp.twrpapp: the android application that keeps TWRP Recovery up to date.). Is it possible to remove this application from the install? Is there an uninstaller? The "App Info" screen only gives me the option to Disable and Force Stop.

When I try to remove it with `pm uninstall`, I get an error,

```
$ pm uninstall me.twrp.twrpapp                                                                                                                
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

The device is rooted, and uninstalling as root didn't seem to help

```
$ adb root
restarting adbd as root
$ adb shell
n1awifi:/ # pm uninstall me.twrp.twrpapp
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

Comment: Just remove the apk wherever it is located under /system/ and /data/. Restart and the app would be gone.

Comment: As you cannot uninstall it from the GUI, the APK most likely resides in `/system/priv-app` and its data is in `/data/data/me.twrp.twrpapp`. Though it's pretty drastic installing something as system app without a proper warning. What if you wanted things done "system-less" to keep the chance for OTAs? Bummer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling TWRP is very easy if you are on the latest version of TWRP Recovery,

Go to TWRP Recovery via Reboot, 
Mount System and other partitions

Now go to Advanced -> Uninstall TWRP APP (Checkbox)

and SWIPE to uninstall

Answer (score 1):

First you have to connect to your device as root. When you do this you should see the `#` prompt,

```
adb kill-shell
adb root
adb shell
```

Now you need to [remount `/system` as rw](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110927/7425) and then you can remove all copies of `twrpapp`

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
find / -name '*twrpapp*' -print -exec rm {} \; 2>/dev/null
```