# ADB Shell / Magisk : Add folder to /system problem

Tags: adb, root-access, internal-storage, file-management

I have an old phone on which I installed a new custom ROM, but the WiFi does not work because `/system/etc/wifi` is missing. I just have to move the vendor's folder from `system/vendor/etc/wifi` with command `mv` in `adb shell`. However, Android won't let me use it as it says that `/system` is "read-only".

So I tried with `adb root`, I was root but did not work. I then tried with `adb shell su -c "chmod -R 755 /system"`, but it still said that it was a read-only directory. Finally, I rooted my phone with Magisk, but still did not work, I got the message "adb cannot run as root in production builds" when I typed `adb root`. So I am really at a loss.

Anyone went through this also? Thanks.

Comment: adb root never works on normal ROMs, thus you have to remount system partition manually.

Comment: Hi, not sure what a normal ROM is, this is not the stock ROM it's a custom ROM. How can I remount system partition ? You mean using TWRP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount /system rewritable or read-only? (RW/RO)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110927/2241)

Comment: Regarding normal/production ROM vs developer/debug ROM: [Why does "adb root" do nothing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213116/44325)

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4561993